# changing characters in char array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I have trouble with the following task:

1. take in limited char array
2. change a given character in array
3. print changed char array

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void change(const char* source, char* target) {
  int j;

  for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    if (source[j] == '.') {
      target[j] = '\n';
    }

    else {
      target[j] = source[j];
    }
  }

  return;
}

int main() {
  int i;
  char input[100] = {0}, output[100] = {0};

  cout << "Bitte geben Sie einen Text ein: " << endl;
  cin >> input[100];

  change(&input[100], &output[100]);

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    cout << output[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'm a student and pretty confused by the whole array/pointer and how to pass them properly to functions topic. Also I'd like to find a solution without utilizing string/getline (), only for better practice.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code has _undefined behavior here_ (and in other places analogously): `input[100]`, if you declared a `char` array with 100 elements, the valid indices are from `0` to `99`. So there's a lot what can go wrong with your program after hitting this line. We cannot tell what happens, but tell you: Don't do that _ever_.

Comment: When asking about homework questions, please try to reduce your question to a **specific** problem that you're having, rather than just saying "My code doesn't work."

Comment: @JarMan Sorry, 2nd time posting here, I'll try to do so for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier than you think, try this version

```
cin >> input;

change(input, output);
```

It's a very common beginner misunderstanding to think that `input[100]` somehow represents the whole array. It doesn't.

When you declare an array the number between the `[]` is the size of the array, but when you use an array the number between the `[]` is the index of the element you wish to access. These are completely different meanings, which you should not confuse. Also since an array of size 100 only has valid indexes from 0 to 99 `input[100]` is actually trying to access an element of the array that does not exist.

The other error is that you need to limit your loops to the actual length of the string, which maybe less than 100.

You can find the length of the string using the `strlen` function, like this

```
int length = strlen(output);
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cout << output[i];
}
```

Comment: A quick  new programmer note on the special sauce that makes `strlen` work. A character array being used to represent a string is always terminated with a special character, null, that cannot exist in a string. `strlen` reads until it finds the terminator. If you forget to place the terminator, `strlen` will keep reading until it finds a terminator, and no one can safely predict when that will be. All character array-based string manipulating functions operate in the same fashion, so you have to keep an eye on those null terminators. Major source of common bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the program:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// only accepts arrays of predetermined length
void change(const char (&source)[100], char (&target)[100])
{
   int j = 0;
   for(; j < 100 && source[j] != '\0'; ++j)
   {
      target[j] = (source[j] == '.') ? '\n' : source[j];
   }
   // make sure we null terminate string
   target[std::min(j, 100 - 1)] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
   char input[100];

   cout << "Bitte geben Sie einen Text ein: " << endl;
   cin >> input; // This reads until first non-whitespace, usually a "word"

   char output[100] = {};
   change(input, output);

   for(int i = 0; i < 100 && output[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      cout << output[i];
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But since the above can really read a text with whitespaces you need a "raw" reader like `std::getline` which will handle this nicely. But since you didn't want a solution with `getline` we can use the `<cstdio>` function `std::fgets`.

Just change the lines:

```cpp
   cout << "Bitte geben Sie einen Text ein: " << endl;
   std::fgets(input, 100, stdin);
```

And we read max 99 characters without the risk of overwriting the buffer.

You can also use `std::scanf`. Below we ask it to read max 100-1 characters and only allow anything until we reach a `\n`. Usually `%s`
would read until the next whitespace.

```cpp
   cout << "Bitte geben Sie einen Text ein: " << endl;
   std::scanf("%100[^\n]s", input);
```